# convert mp4 to gif - gif not moving

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am using this command to convert my mp4 to gif

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

but the resulting gif does not move. I also get many of this message

```
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 46, current: 16; changing to 47. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 47, current: 16; changing to 48. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 48, current: 16; changing to 49. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 49, current: 17; changing to 50. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 50, current: 17; changing to 51. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000002809f53ef00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 51, current: 17; changing to 52. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

My video is 300 fps

Comment: AFAIK, 300 fps gifs are not possible. That may or may not be contributing to the error.

Comment: Total guess, but perhaps your input file is broken somehow. Your command worked fine for me on (what claimed to be and `ffprobe` reported as) a 300 FPS `.avi` sample file downloaded from the internet. That said, my understanding is `rgb24` isn't supported by the gif codec in `ffmpeg`. Perhaps try `rgb8`.